# How to get first value of a column using sequel and ruby?

Tags: ruby, sequel

Here is the database connection code

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.connect('jdbc:mysql://localhost/idemcon?user=root&password=root&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull', :max_connections => 10)
```

Below is a query to fetch the sum of a column from a MySQL table

Using first method

```
DB.fetch("SELECT SUM(bill) AS total FROM invoice WHERE provider = '#{provider}' AND invoicedate BETWEEN '#{fromdate}' AND '#{thrudate}';").first[:total] || 0
```

OR

Using map method and selecting element at zeroth index

```
DB.fetch("SELECT SUM(bill) AS total FROM invoice WHERE provider = '#{provider}' AND invoicedate BETWEEN '#{fromdate}' AND '#{thrudate}';").map(:total)[0] || 0
```

Note: I may get null in some cases so that's why appended `|| 0` to the end of the query

**Is there a better way? If not Which one should I use?**

Comment: SUM(bill) should return a single row.  Why do you need to use MAP to iterate over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the best way to do what you want:

```
DB[:invoices].
  where(:provider=>provider, :invoice_date=>fromdate..thrudate).
  sum(:bill)
```

Note that the code you provided may have up to three SQL injection vulnerabilities, depending on whether the variable values are provided by the user.